# Assigning DateRangePicker value to a Text box using jquery

Tags: jquery

I wanted to assign daterangepicker value to a text box in order to store the new selected date to a database. Though i tried this but didn't work as i expected.

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="" name="docrcvd" value="<?php echo $res->doc_date; ?>" class="form-control col-md-12" disabled="disabled">
                               <input type="text" id="birthday1" class="fa fa-calendar date-picker ">
```

This works fine and it populate the date stored in database and the second input filed display the datepicker.

But the problem is once i selected new date it won't assign the newly selected date to the first input field.

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                      $('#birthday1').daterangepicker({
                            onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
                               $('#docrcvd').val(dateText);
                            }
                         });
                  });
```

Any help or suggestion would appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the ID for your input field.

```
<input type="text" id="" name="docrcvd" value="<?php echo $res->doc_date; ?>" class="form-control col-md-12" disabled="disabled">
                           <input type="text" id="birthday1" class="fa fa-calendar date-picker ">
```

has to look like this

```
<input type="text" id="docrcvd" name="docrcvd" value="<?php echo $res->doc_date; ?>" class="form-control col-md-12" disabled="disabled">
                           <input type="text" id="birthday1" class="fa fa-calendar date-picker ">
```

You are using the ID Selector '#elementId'

```
$('#docrcvd').val(dateText);
```

But you did not assign that id to your element so your code would never find your input field to fill it.

Comment: Thank you TeryX. I have done the changes as per your suggestions. But, still didn't update the first filed(ID="docrcvd"). Any other suggestion you might think of would be appreciated. Thank you again.

Comment: To update the data stored in the database you have to notify the Server about the changes you made. A common way to do this is to create an ajax request

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp

You then need to handle that on server-side with (probably in your case)  an PHP file to write these changes to the database

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php may help you

Comment: Thank you Teryx and the issue is resolved as per your suggestion.